# MaaS 2.2rc2 - DHCP Relay help

Tags: 16.04, maas, dhcp

Our MaaS KVM VM is setup on a server with an IP of 10.62.7.140 (10.62.7.129/26), we have DHCP helpers enabled on switches and forwarding traffic from our iLO network - 10.62.0.0/22. I have created a new VLAN and subnet for that VLAN with DHCP Relay (Per this document https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/devel/en/installconfig-network-dhcp). BUT, this subnet is not showing up in the controller - so I'm unable to create nodes and assign addresses, through DHCP, for this network - 10.62.0.0/22 (iLO) is to be controlled via DHCP and our provisioning network is 10.62.16.0/22.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the top level `Subnets` tab to browse to the subnet and define dynamic IP ranges, then browse to the VLAN and enable DHCP. You'll need to enable DHCP on the VLAN which is present on the rack controller. Then you should see that `/var/lib/maas/dhcpd.conf` on the rack controller has been written with a `shared-network` entry for the remote VLAN.

If the remote subnet isn't showing up in the `VLANs` tab on the controller details page, that [could be considered a bug, and should be filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+filebug).